# Ambiguous compilation error with Maven and apache utils

Tags: java, apache, maven, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

I'm using `org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils` in the `commons-lang3` (version 3.1).
When I try to compile next line of code

```
BooleanUtils.xor(true, true);
```

using `maven-compiler-plugin` (version 3.3), I'm getting a compilation failure message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project exchange: Compilation failure
[ERROR] MyClass.java:[33,34] reference to xor is ambiguous, both method xor(boolean...) in org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils and method xor(java.lang.Boolean...) in org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils match
```

I use Java 1.7.0_55 to compile.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem happens because the signature of the method has variable arguments. When a method is invoked, there are 3 phases during which all applicable methods are searched. Methods with variable arguments are searched in [phase 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) where boxing, and unboxing is also allowed.

So both `xor(boolean...)` and `xor(Boolean...)` are applicable here because boxing is taken into account. When multiple methods are applicable, only the most specific is invoked. But in this case, `boolean` and `Boolean` can't be compared, so there is no more specific method, hence the compiler error: both methods match.

A workaround is to create an explicit array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    xor(new boolean[] { true, false }); // will call the primitive xor
    xor(new Boolean[] { Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE }); // will call the non-primitive xor
}

private static Boolean xor(Boolean... booleans) {
    System.out.println("Boolean...");
    return Boolean.TRUE;
}

private static boolean xor(boolean... booleans) {
    System.out.println("boolean...");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This works, but for me looks like really bad code :) I was surprized that this can happen in the apcahe-commons-lengs3

Answer (score 0):

Funny : a corner case where autoboxing go straight in your way.

The simplest way to fix that is to write

```
BooleanUtils.xor((boolean) true, (boolean) true)
```

Comment: Actually, the simplest way to write it is `false`.

Comment: Actually, this does not solve the compiler error. It is still there, even with the explicit cast

Comment: I can verify that this causes a compiler error.  It's the first thing I tried before coming here.  The Java compiler still can't tell whether the type of the array is boolean or Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rip out the method you want and put it in your own util class.
Just don't copy both or you'll be back to square one.

```
public final class MyUtils {
    /**
     * @see BooleanUtils#xor(boolean...)
     */
    public static boolean xor(final boolean... array) {
        // Validates input
        if (array == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Array must not be null");
        }
        if (array.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array is empty");
        }

        // false if the neutral element of the xor operator
        boolean result = false;
        for (final boolean element : array) {
            result ^= element;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```